# SO(3) maximal subgroup

Tags: group-theory

I would like to know if $$\left\{\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&0\\0&\cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)\\0&\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta) \end{array}\right),\ \theta\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$$

is a maximal subgroup of $SO(3)$ ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: My guess (didn't check even nearly everything) would be that it is not maximal, but feels like it is a maximal **connected** subgroup. The idea was that the stabilizer of the $x$-axis also contains 180 degree rotations about axes perpendicular to it, and those are missing from your group. OTOH, the real Lie algebra has no two dimensional subalgebras, and that seems to deny the possibility of a 2-dimensional subgroup. Alternatively, if we add an element that doesn't map the $x$-axis to itself, we then also get rotations about the image of the $x$-axis, and things snowball from there.

Comment: You're right, it is not.

If we add $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}-1&0&0\\0&-1&0\\0&0&1\end{array}\right)$ to this group we will not generate all $SO(3)$.

The idea was to use the action of $SO(3)$ on $S^2$ to prove that it's a simple group with the Iwasawa criterion, but it won't work since it's not a maximal subgroup then the action is not primitive.

Comment: On the other hand, the overgroup of index 2 given by P.Vd is a maximal subgroup.